# using import re [regex] to extract only numbers and put commas in between

Tags: regex, beautifulsoup

I have a string like below I got from beautifulsoup. I want the digits attached to the store such as `0` and `1`. And the numbers like `36` `37` represent shoe sizes. My ideal output is below. How can I achieve this?[link](https://www.nakedcph.com/asics-gel-kayano-5-og/p/7319)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = """b'{"36":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"1"},
"37":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"37,5":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"38":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"39":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"39,5":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"40":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"1"},
"40,5":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"1"},
"41,5":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"42":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"}}'"""

no_stock = re.findall('"aarhus":"(\-?\.?\d+)"|"pilestraede":"(\-?\.?\d+)"|"klosterstraede":"(\-?\.?\d+)', text)
print(no_stock)
```

print(size):

`[('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '1'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '0'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '0'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '0'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '0'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '0'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '1'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '1'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '0'), ('0', '', ''), ('', '0', ''), ('', '', '0')]`

what I want is:

`[('0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0')]`

Comment: Are you sure your `text` is exactly like that? Is it not `text = b'''...'''`?

Comment: not sure why `b` is there but I see it in my result. If its bothering, please ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you grabbed this data from Javascript/JSON as bytes and did `str()` on it, so you need to do two times `literal_eval()` to decode it. I would sugest running `literal_eval()` immediately after you grab the data, without the `str()` intermediate step.

```
from itertools import chain
from ast import literal_eval

text = """b'{"36":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"1"},
"37":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"37,5":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"38":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"39":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"39,5":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"40":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"1"},
"40,5":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"1"},
"41,5":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"},
"42":{"aarhus":"0","pilestraede":"0","klosterstraede":"0"}}'"""

d = literal_eval(text.replace('\n', ''))
d = literal_eval(d.decode('utf-8'))

l = chain.from_iterable([v.values() for k, v in d.items()])
print([*l])
```

Prints:

```
['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help.Frankly, they're not in javascript/json format hence that was why I was struggling. I wouldve been grabbing json if it was in the format under the `script` tag. Im attaching the link in my post.

Comment: @Hachi Looking at the link, grab with `re` the string immediately after `data-model=(.*?)\n` and run `literal_eval()` on this string.

Comment: I did `inventory = soup.findAll('section',{'class':'store-status-item-container'})[0].get('data-model')` to get the content after `data-model`. Youre saying I do re.findall against the ivnentory? Just trying to learn from you.

Comment: @Hachi Yes, you have right, I saw it badly. Grab it from the attribute as you said and do `literal_eval()` on it.

Comment: I encountered `'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'` while doing as told. If I put this `inventory = str(inventory.encode('utf-8'))` before the literal_eval, it works. Am I doing it right? Must encode first before decode.

Comment: @Hachi depends what are you getting from BeautifulSoup: if bytes then `decode()` to `str`. If `str()` then you are done.